Не удается подключиться к серверу при запуске через Docker org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: localhost:8080 failed to respond
пишу проект на Go при запуске на локальной машине напрямую go run main.go все работает нормально и получается отправлять запрос и получать ответ. Но при запуске с докер-компоуза я не могу достучаться до адреса в JetBrain клиенте org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: localhost:8080 failed to respond, Postman - Error: socket hang up. Вроде я указал порты 8080:8080 в ports компоуза но всеравно не понимаю в чем проблема
  postgres:
    container_name: 'why404postgres'
    image: 'postgres:15.3-alpine'
    ports:
      - '5435:5432'
    restart: 'unless-stopped'
    env_file:
      - '../config/.env'
    volumes:
      - pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  app:
    container_name: "why404app"
    build: 
      context: ../
      dockerfile: build/Dockerfile
    stop_signal: SIGTERM
    restart: 'unless-stopped'
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

volumes:
  pg_data:


Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example // как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
